# Finding Edit function in Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode

I am working my way through the Apple developer tutorials on Storyboards and have been stuck for many hours on what should be a very simple step.

In the web page https://developer.apple.com/library/iOS/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/RoadMapiOS/SecondTutorial.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011343-CH8-SW1 Apple describes the following:

"*You have two view controllers configured in the storyboard, but there’s no connection between them. Transitions between scenes are called segues.
Before creating a segue, you need to configure your scenes. First, you’ll wrap your to-do list table view controller in a navigation controller. Recall from Defining the Interaction that navigation controllers provide a navigation bar and keep track of the navigation stack. You’ll add a button to this navigation bar to transition to the add-to-do-item scene.
To add a navigation controller to your table view controller
In the outline view, select Table View Controller.
With the view controller selected, choose Editor > Embed In > Navigation Controller.*"

I cannot find an "Editor" button, so I can't use the "Embed In" function. (I am not using a Mac keyboard, but I can't find a keyboard command which may invoke "Editor" either).

I can right-click on the Table View Controller which displays a menu which includes "Embed". I can drag from the "Embed" radio button to other screens, but there is no navigation controller to drag it to. Dragging it to a "Navigation Controller" in the list of available controls (bottom right) has no effect.

This tutorial is great, and explains things in detail. But I have spent many hours trying to find how/where I "*choose Editor > Embed In > Navigation Controller*". Can anybody help?

Here is a screen shot:

[image]

Answer (score 5):

To get what you need first select storyboard.

Then select the view controller.

Now in menu you will see Editor>>Embed In >> Navigation Controller.

[image]

### *To get embed in, you have to select view controller in storyboard.*

---

The problem indeed was that your xcode was full screen mode.

To remove full screen mode, just take mouse over on the top side and click the last button on the right side as shown below.

[image]

Comment: Thankyou (both Fahim and Inertastic). But I don't have a menu bar in Xcode (Find, Navigate, Editor etc). It looks similar to your screen shot but without the menu bar. That explains an earlier difficulty with using the "File" command! At the top of the screen I just have the close/minimise/maximise buttons and underneath "Run" and "Stop".  Below that are the various editing windows which appear. Right clicking on anywhere at the top of the windows just gives me options for "Icon", "Text", "Icon and Text". How do I get my menu bar back?

Comment: @PeterWebb : Post your screenshot... ***Make sure you have selected view controller in storyboard...***

Comment: If you're in full screen mode, move the mouse pointer to the very top of the screen and the menu bar will appear.

Comment: Screenshot added. (As I am a complete newb for Apple, even this required Googling!)

Comment: Thanks to everyone who responded. I just stumbled across a solution. If you are in full screen mode and move your mouse to the very top of the Xcode window and move it down slowly, the menu bar magically appears. Still don't know how to do this in non-full-screen-mode. I assume that people who use Macs would know this already.

Comment: @FahimParkar I can't see an "accept answer" button (I'm having a lot of trouble with UIs today) so I simply upvoted. I think I must have had some hide function on the (global) menu bar, so it never appeared. Never having used a Mac until two days ago, and only for XCode, I didn't know what I was missing. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Editor is a menu in Xcode. Select the view controller you want to embed in a navigation controller in your storyboard. On the top of your screen, find Editor, and Embed In is an option in the drop down list.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem , after pressing these button in this other all windows apears.

before that only had code window without any bars.

[image]